# illustrate layers of artificial NN

Tags: python, neural-network

I have a NN here:

```
model = keras.models.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Conv2D(64, 7, activation="relu", padding="same",
                        input_shape = [40, 40, 1]),
    keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2),
    keras.layers.Conv2D(128, 3, activation="relu", padding="same"),
    keras.layers.Conv2D(128, 3, activation="relu", padding="same"),
    keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2),
    keras.layers.Conv2D(256, 3, activation="relu", padding="same"),
    keras.layers.Conv2D(256, 3, activation="relu", padding="same"),
    keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2),
    keras.layers.Flatten(),
    keras.layers.Dense(128, activation="relu"),
    keras.layers.Dropout(0.5),
    keras.layers.Dense(64, activation="relu"),
    keras.layers.Dropout(0.5),
    keras.layers.Dense(8, activation="softmax")
])
```

that I want to visualize like these guys do in the upper right section with the "models" title:

http://cs230.stanford.edu/projects_fall_2019/posters/26259758.pdf

Does anyone know a tool I can use to make this a simple process?

Comment: i've never seen such tool, maybe u can draw a diagram on your own